# An experiment consists of selecting a card at random from a 52-card deck. What is the probability that a club or a king is drawn?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, card-games

what I did is P(a Club or a king)= (13+4)/52=0.327
But the answer is wrong.
Can someone explain me where I did wrong and what would be the correct way to solve?

Comment: It is not true that $\frac {17}{52}=0.327$.  That is the correctly rounded three digit approximation, but in math $=$ means equals.  It would be better to use  \approx to get $\approx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You counted the king of clubs twice, once as a king and once as a club.  There are only $13+4-1$ cards that are either a king or club, where $1$ is the number of cards that are both.  You may have seen $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$ and you have lost the third term.